# Validation on multivalue HTTP header with Node and hapijs/joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I'm trying to validate an Accept header in my REST api written in Node.js on Hapijs framework. When I request my resource from Firefox which creates a request with following accept header:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Now my route looks like this:

```
{
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/cities',
      handler: function (req, reply) {
        ... handler ...
      },
      config: {
        validate: {
          headers: Joi.object({
            'accept': Joi.any().valid('application/json').required()
          }).unknown()
        }
      } 
}
```

Now I figured out that Joi does not split accept header into some kind of array. I could use some regex like:

```
Joi.string().regex(/(application\/json)/)
```

I wonder if there is any other way then regex to validate such multivalues headers especially when api versioning will come into play. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is as long as the `Accept` header is a string.

I think you're on the right track with using `regex()`.

Note that the casing of `Accept` needs to be consistent between your schema and the header attribute.